# Java naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have been trying to learn Java for the past week, and have been able to produce reasonable codes so far. However, I seem to have a problem in understanding the Java naming convention.

I just looked at a tutorial which says that class names should start with an upper case. If I look at the codes so far I have wrote, I have actually used lower case names, such as:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class orange implements Comparator {
    public int mango(...) {
    }
}

class jason {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        {
            // Content here
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both my class names start with a lower case.

When I compile and execute the program, I don't get any compile errors, and everything works as expected. I should have thought, since the class name starts with lower case, it would end up with a compile error: but this hasn't happened. Why?

If it helps, I run [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) and [IcedTea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea).

Comment: It is not forced by compiler. It is [a naming convention defined in JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.8.2).

Comment: This code **SHOULD NOT** compile. Invalid syntax.

Comment: Sergei, Can you explain why you said invalid syntax? what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A naming convention is a rule to follow as you decide what to name
> your identifiers (e.g. class, package, variable, method, etc..) and it
> is not an EXCEPTION.

A good programmer must and will follow the naming conventions specified in any programming language for a neat and effective program.

Refer to [this page](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for more Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 6):

Naming conventions are just *conventions*, not rules. The Java language spec doesn't care either way. But if you don't stick to the conventions, your code will be difficult for other people to read and understand, so you really should stick to them.

Answer (score 5):

It's a convention, not a compiler rule.

You can break it if you wish, but I recommend following the convention.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not about compiler syntax. It is about following coding conventions.

And you missed the convention in your code

**See**

- [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: The link is broken: *"We can't find the page you were looking for."*

Comment: [The conventional page](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html#367) is from the 1990s: *"The information on this page is for archive purposes only. This page is not being actively maintained. Links within the documentation may not work and the information itself may no longer be valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999"*

Answer (score 1):

It's a convention that class names start with upper case, but the compiler does not enforce it. Same with method names (though they start with lower case).

I have *never* seen class names with lower case. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler doesn't enforce naming conventions. It's called a *convention* for a reason: to facilitate reading of code. For example, when you see an `orange`, it's probably a variable, and there isn't any need to go look it up. And in your case, readers of your code will be *quite* surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken the naming convention, not the syntax of the language - which is why your code compiles without error.

Naming conventions are used primarily to improve readability in source code and to reduce the effort needed to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a language which is widely used worldwide. There are lot of applications built in Java every moment.

It is not necessary that the same code will be worked upon / maintained by the same developer throughout its lifetime. Hence, to avoid ambiguity and keep it simple to understand and reuse, a naming convention is followed.

Guess what would happen if each of us use our own conventions. It will put an adverse effect on code reusability, because it will take lot of time for other programmers to understand the code before working on it. Hence, it is required that every Java developer knows and follows the standard protocols so that each of are on same page.